# Clustering sets by set difference

Tags: optimization, sets, clustering

Suppose you have $n$ nonequal sets $S_1, \ldots, S_n$ and some constant $0 \le k < n$. The goal of *set clustering* is to find a partition of the set $\mathbf{S} = \{S_1, \ldots, S_n\}$ such that the sum of the *total distance* for each subset of $\mathbf{S}$ is minimized and such that $\mathrm{cardinality}(\mathbf{S}) = k$ (in reality, this latter constraint is not quite so tight, but the size of $\mathbf{S}$ must be less than $k$, and hopefully near it). The *total distance* $d$ of a set $X \in \mathbf{S}$ is $d(X) = \sum_{A, B \in X} \mathrm{cardinality}(A \ominus B)$ where $\ominus$ is symmetric difference. Assume for the purposes of the problem that the sets consume $O(1)$ space (so symmetric difference can be computed in constant time).

Is there a good greedy linear(ithmic) heuristic for this problem? Is there any literature on this problem, or similar ones?

---

All I've come up with so far is an $O(n^2 \log n)$ heuristic that looks like:

1. Set $I = \{1, \ldots, n\}$
2. Choose some $i \in I$
3. Emit a cluster $C \subset I$ containing all $m \in I$ such that $\mathrm{cardinality}(S_i \ominus S_m) \le d_\mathrm{max}$.
4. Set $I = I - C$
5. Go to step 2.

where this process occurs in each step of a binary search that finds the best value of $d_\mathrm{max}$ for a given $k$.

I was thinking that if there were some way to sort the list of sets such that nearby sets in the list have small symmetric difference, then a linearithmic solution might be easy to write.

Comment: $k$ is $O(n)$ and I stated that symmetric difference takes constant time

Comment: I don't know, for a handwavy intutition why you might be able to do better, consider something like turning each set into a point in an $n$-dimensional space (where $n$ is the number of elements in the union of all sets in the input), and then encoding each point as a position along a morton-order spacefilling curve. Then sort by those positions and break the list evenly into $k$ chunks.

Comment: Naively, just computing the distance between all pairs of sets takes $O(n^2)$ time, so asking for a $O(n)$ time solution seems like a lot to ask for.  In fact, just evaluating how good a candidate solution is takes $O(n^2)$ time (or $O(n^2/k)$ time if each partition is of about the same size).